# Group by with the forecast package in R

Tags: r, forecasting, subset

I am working on several analyses where I would like to forecast some numeric value for each level of a factor or even multiple factors, e.g. condition on sex and age. My process so far has been fairly manual, something like below, which is fine for one variable/factor with say 2-5 levels. But it is not scalable to condition on factors with many levels or on multiple factors.

Is there any kind of "group by" or "subset" functionality within the forecast package that would help? I started writing a program to do the below process in the most general case (i.e. for any number of factors and levels) but have not been too successful yet.

BTW, unfortunately my data is private and I cannot share it here. But it shouldn't really matter, because the code below works and I'm looking for a better, i.e. scalable, solution.

```
# Example code

# category is a factor with levels A and B; amt is the variable to model/forecast
# using data.table syntax to create a vector for each category
vec1 <- dt[category == 'A']$amount
vec2 <- dt[category == 'B']$amount

# Create ts objects from above vectors
ts1 <- ts(vec1, start=c(start_year, start_month), end=c(end_year, end_month), frequency=12)
ts2 <- ts(vec2, start=c(start_year, start_month), end=c(end_year, end_month), frequency=12)

# Fit model 
fit1 <- auto.arima(ts1, trace = TRUE, stepwise = FALSE)
fit2 <- auto.arima(ts2, trace = TRUE, stepwise = FALSE)


# Forecast out using selected models
h <- 12
fcast1 <- forecast(fit1, h)
fcast2 <- forecast(fit2, h)

# funggcast pulls out data from the forecast object into a df (needed for ggplot2)
# output columns are date, observed, fitted, forecast, lo80, hi80, lo95, hi95
fcastdf1 <- funggcast(ts1, fcast1)
fcastdf2 <- funggcast(ts2, fcast2)

# Add in category
fcastdf1$category <- 'A'
fcastdf2$category <- 'B'


# Merge into one df
df <- merge(fcastdf1, fcastdf2, all=T)

# Basic qplot from ggplot2 package, I am actually incorporating quite a bit more formatting but this is just to give an idea
qplot(x=date, 
      y=observed, 
      data=df, 
      color=category, 
      group=category, geom="line") +
geom_line(aes(y=forecast), col='blue')
```

Comment: It looks to me that most of your code can be wrapped up in a function that takes `vec` (e.g. `dt[category == 'A']$amount`) and returns corresponding `fcastdf`. Then, for a given list of `vec`s, you'd be able to use `lapply` and `as.data.frame` to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are correct, and I will start there as it solves probably 90% of my problem. The final complication lies in the desire to automate even the process of selecting and creating those initial vectors, since I might need to create upwards of 50 if I have enough "slices".

Comment: I guess more knowledge about the input data set as well as the selection process might make this process more straightforward. Maybe, you want to perform the forecast for every category in your data set? Then, you can `melt` your data and use something `dlply` from the `plyr` package, or similar tools from `dplyr` or `data.table` packages (I guess the latter might be your choice, as you already using data.table).

Comment: I understand and thanks for your help despite having no info about the input data. Finally figured out the last part. I ended up using expand.grid to create a list with all unique combinations. Can't believe I forgot about that function. Unfortunately, I couldn't get mapply to work correctly. I think it's because it somehow coerces all my arguments into vectors, but I need them as lists. (Is that true for all functions in the apply family?) There are more for loops hanging around than I would like, but it still runs super fast because my data sets are not very big.

Comment: BTW I did not need to use melt (or similar alternative) as I already structured my data tables to be "long", as Hadley would say. Just needed to rbindlist() at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `tapply`:

```
  res <- tapply(amount, category, function(x) {
    ts <- ts(x, start = start, frequency = 12)
    fit <- auto.arima(ts, trace = TRUE, stepwise = FALSE)
    fcastdf <- forecast(fit, h = h)
    return(fcastdf)
  })
```

This will return a named list of forecasts.

You will have to set the start to be the earliest date in your data set.